# What is the ideal way to define utility/ helper methods that may need to modify $scope data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, service, private

Task:
Within a controller I have a default object which needs to be modified based on a number of conditions.
The modification logic is repetitive hence I ported it to a service/ utility called colorService (can create a private method as well).
The ask is to set only one color to true and others to false.

**Case 1:**

```
//CONTROLLER
$scope.colorObj = {
        red:true,
        green:true,
        blue:true,
        white:true,
        yellow:true
    };

$scope.changeColor = function(){
var color = 'r';
switch(color){
                case 'r':colorService.setColor('red',$scope.colorObj);break;
                case 'b':colorService.setColor('blue',$scope.colorObj);break;
                case 'g':colorService.setColor('green',$scope.colorObj);break;
                case 'w':colorService.setColor('white',$scope.colorObj);break;
                case 'y':colorService.setColor('yellow',$scope.colorObj);break;
                default: colorService.setColor('',$scope.colorObj);break;
            }
}

//SERVICE
colorService.setColor = function(type, colorObj){
        angular.forEach(colorObj,function(val,color){
            if(color === type){
                colorObj[color] = true;
            }else{
                colorObj[color] = false;
            }
        });
    };
```

If I follow this approach, then the changes get reflected on the $scope.colorObj immediately as the object reference is shared. Hence a 'return' is not needed.

But this approach passes the $scope to the service as an argument which I know is not a best practice. Also, the service method doesn't have a return statement which goes against the grain of a service as well.

**Case 2:**

```
//CONTROLLER
$scope.colorObj = {
        red:true,
        green:true,
        blue:true,
        white:true,
        yellow:true
    };

$scope.changeColor = function(){
var color = 'r';
switch(color){
                case 'r': $scope.colorObj = colorService.setColor('red');break;
                case 'b': $scope.colorObj = colorService.setColor('blue');break;
                case 'g': $scope.colorObj = colorService.setColor('green');break;
                case 'w': $scope.colorObj = colorService.setColor('white');break;
                case 'y': $scope.colorObj = colorService.setColor('yellow');break;
                default:  $scope.colorObj = colorService.setColor('');break;
            }
}

//SERVICE
colorService.setColor = function(type){
       var colorObj = {
                        red:true,
                        green:true,
                        blue:true,
                        white:true,
                        yellow:true
                    };
        angular.forEach(colorObj,function(val,color){
            if(color === type){
                colorObj[color] = true;
            }else{
                colorObj[color] = false;
            }
        });
        return colorObj;
    };
```

In this case, I have isolated the $scope but had to add a local object colorObj in the service method which is returned and copied onto the $scope.colorObj.

I find this more testable but again I need to maintain multiple colorObj in controller and service.

**Case 3:**

```
//CONTROLLER
$scope.colorObj = {
        red:true,
        green:true,
        blue:true,
        white:true,
        yellow:true
    };

$scope.changeColor = function(){
var color = 'r';
switch(color){
                case 'r': setColor('red');break;
                case 'b': setColor('blue');break;
                case 'g': setColor('green');break;
                case 'w': setColor('white');break;
                case 'y': setColor('yellow');break;
                default:  setColor('');break;
            }
};

setColor = function(type){
        angular.forEach(colorObj,function(val,color){
            if(color === type){
               $scope.colorObj[color] = true;
            }else{
               $scope.colorObj[color] = false;
            }
        });
    };
```

Here, I can simply create a private method setColor within the controller to get things done. The downside is that setColor is not uniquely testable; yes, it can be tested by initiating a test for the parent method changeColor

Which option would be a better one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go ahead with case 2. reason being : the logic is separated between service and controller. the code is more testable.

for case 1 : passing $scope is a code smell.

for case 3 : you are loosing test-ability.